# Insert a password to a wallet.dat file from windows cmd

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli, windows, rescan

Is there a way to insert a password to a wallet.dat file from windows cmd?

I'm a newbie, so please be as specific as you can.

That wallet.dat file needs rescan, which I want to make after I insert the password. This I can't do from bitcoin core gui (version 0.22), since once running it starts rescanning immediately and so no menu appears and I can't do anything till it's finished the rescan.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the info @Prayank provided, I managed to do it the following way:

Run first cmd session and changed directory to where `bitcoind.exe` resides. Then run `bitcoind.exe`

Run second cmd session, changed directory to the same one as above and then run

`bitcoin-cli loadwallet directory_where_wallet.dat_resides`

`bitcoin-cli encryptwallet "my pass phrase"`

Comment: Cool. I think I misunderstood earlier and was not aware that wallet is not encrypted already.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to insert a password to a wallet.dat file from windows cmd?

1. Run cmd
2. Change directory to run `bitcoind.exe`. If Windows is installed in `C` drive:

   ```
   cd "C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\daemon"
   ```
3. Open another command prompt, change directory to above path and run this command:

   ```
   bitcoin-cli.exe walletpassphrase "my pass phrase" 60
   ```

   https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/wallet/walletpassphrase/

You can also do this using PowerShell. However I am not sure if this will help with `rescan` issue.

Comment: Thanks @Prayank ! You can check my answer for how I did it